# node_load() Performance and alternatives

Tags: nodes, 6

I created a custom module which lists the last X nodes from a certain content type, with the following query:

```
SELECT n.title, r.teaser, r.timestamp
FROM node n
INNER JOIN node_revisions r ON r.vid = n.vid
INNER JOIN term_node tn ON tn.nid = n.nid
INNER JOIN term_data t ON t.tid = tn.tid
WHERE t.name= 'breaking_news'
AND n.status = 1
ORDER BY n.nid DESC LIMIT 25
```

Then I do a `node_load($nid)` to check if there is a image and an audio file inside, for example

```
$mynode = node_load($queryresutl->nid);
if ($mynode->field_efe_audio[0]['filepath']) {  
  $audio = 'yep, has audio'; 
}
```

But I've read that `node_load()` could be a performance killer, so I wonder if this is true and if there's is an alternative to check fields in my module?

Comment: Did you try to directly query the field_data_field_efe_audio table using your nid as etid ?

Comment: Do you mean, query the field_data_field_efe_audio table for each node ? I didn't. Should be better than node_load()?

Comment: Yeah definitely, since `node_load` will query all field attached to your nodes. Other solution actually would be create a custom table that get updated on node creation/update/delete only if the current node contains an audio content, you can then just query that table. I think both solutions should be pretty much same performance, just a matter of organization

Comment: To answer the question "is node_load slower" use the devel module -> [Use the Devel module to analyze performance](http://www.morningtime.com/Drupal-6x-Performance-Guide/II-Advanced-Drupal-Performance-P/Use-the-Devel-module-to-analyze/546) to test the different solutions. As "ram4nd" suggests, caching might be the real solution -> [A beginner's guide to caching data in Drupal 7](http://www.lullabot.com/articles/beginners-guide-caching-data-drupal-7).

Comment: Thank you! let me check the link about devel module and performance analysis. Im already using cache in my custom module but in some sections I cant cache for a long time, just a few minutes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First i would make sure that using [node_load()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_load/7) does slower your script. If you are sure it really does you can either:

- 1- Create an `index_audio`  table with a nid and `use_audio` columns.
  You could update this table on node `creation/update/delete`. Then
  you can just query this table to make sure a specific node does have
  audio attached to it. I would use that solution only if i you have to
  intensively make such a check
- 2- Directly query your field table with your `nid` as `etid`, in your
  instance : `field_data_field_efe_audio` table see if it returns
  `FALSE` or some actual data

Comment: Well I also need the image filepath so maybe solution 1 doesnt fit my needs, but #2 could be. The thing I trying to figure out is  if 2 queries per node are better than one call to node_load! Thank you

Comment: It will be faster as this you query less data from the DB.. Now is it worth the trouble ? I guess it probably depends on how complex is your node, and how intensively will this query run on your production site.